How to prevent Vue from update/patch the DOM for manually added elements
I need to embed leaflet charts and HiCharts charts in my UI, and for performance reasons I want to keep using the leaflet/hicharts API directly.
Unfortunately, with my version of Vue (3.4.21) an HiCharts (3.0.10), I get JS errors from what seems to be unwelcome traversions of the DOM from Vue.
The reason for the ancient HiCharts version are licensing issue, an this version has all the functionality we need.
I have redone the HiCharts/Vue widget so that the embedding div is realized with h('div', ... in the hope that Vue would then not attempt traversing the tree. Also, using "v-pre" and "v-once" does not seem to have any bearing on this
FWIW: I get the following error after a few clicks in a  densely populated 'arearange' widget. Simple datasets seem to work fine.
Uncaught (in promise) NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 
The node before which   the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    
        at insert (vue.global.js?svn=24345:9618:14)
        at processFragment (vue.global.js?svn=24345:7292:9)
        at patch (vue.global.js?svn=24345:6804:11)
        at patchKeyedChildren (vue.global.js?svn=24345:7814:13)
        at patchChildren (vue.global.js?svn=24345:7686:13)
        at processFragment (vue.global.js?svn=24345:7325:11)
        at patch (vue.global.js?svn=24345:6804:11)
        at patchKeyedChildren (vue.global.js?svn=24345:7772:11)
        at patchChildren (vue.global.js?svn=24345:7686:13)
        at patchElement (vue.global.js?svn=24345:7125:9)

This is also asked as a comment on a Reddit/Vue thread
